# Creating an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, syntax

I am trying to create an array in Ruby. When my function is called to print the array, it seems that the array is undefined. I am wondering if my syntax is off.

Can someone please tell me if this is the correct way to create and instantiate an array in one line, or if the problem is somewhere else in my code?

Below is my Ruby code:

```
    class Game         

        words = Array["hat", "cat", "ate", "run", "eye", "soup", "date",
              "bake", "wake", "grape", "apple", "pride", "drive",
               "tacos", "linux", "orange", "purple", "volume", 
               "liquid", "palace", "molasses", "diamond", "sausage",
               "america", "england"]    


         # starts the game state to play
         def start_x
             #  game logic for begin
             puts(words)
         end

        # if users wins
        def win
             puts("congratulations! you win!")

        end

        # if user loses 
        def death
            puts("sorry! you die!")

         end



   end
```

Comment: "I am wondering if my syntax is off." – Since your method gets called, your syntax is obviously okay, since for your method to be called, the code has to actually run, and in order to run, the code has to be parsed, and in order to be parsed, it has to be free of syntax errors. If you don't get a `SyntaxError` exception, then your syntax is okay. If you want to check your syntax, you can use the `-c` option for the `ruby` command to check the syntax.

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd: While your array creation  is obviously correct, if you are a lazy typer, an easier way would be `words=%w(cat ate run .... england)`. However, you can not access the variable `words` from inside your methods. You could make it for instance a variable associated to the class, i.e. `@@words=%w(....)`, and then of course output it as `puts @@words`.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to constantize `words` into `WORDS` or you need to make those values available through a getter method or an instance variable. Here are some examples:

Constantize, making the array available to any caller:

```
class Game
  WORDS = ['hat', 'cat', 'ate', 'run', 'eye', 'soup', 'date',
    'bake', 'wake', 'grape', 'apple', 'pride', 'drive',
    'tacos', 'linux', 'orange', 'purple', 'volume', 
    'liquid', 'palace', 'molasses', 'diamond', 'sausage',
    'america', 'england']

  def start_x
    puts(WORDS)
  end
end
```

And then it works:

```
⇒ Game.new.start_x
hat
cat
ate
run
eye
soup
date
bake
wake
grape
apple
pride
drive
tacos
linux
orange
purple
volume
liquid
palace
molasses
diamond
sausage
america
england
```

Or with a getter method:

```
class Game
  def words
    @words ||= ['hat', 'cat', 'ate', 'run', 'eye', 'soup', 'date',
      'bake', 'wake', 'grape', 'apple', 'pride', 'drive',
      'tacos', 'linux', 'orange', 'purple', 'volume', 
      'liquid', 'palace', 'molasses', 'diamond', 'sausage',
      'america', 'england']
  end

  def start_x
    puts(words)
  end
end
```

Or with an instance variable:

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @words = ['hat', 'cat', 'ate', 'run', 'eye', 'soup', 'date',
      'bake', 'wake', 'grape', 'apple', 'pride', 'drive',
      'tacos', 'linux', 'orange', 'purple', 'volume', 
      'liquid', 'palace', 'molasses', 'diamond', 'sausage',
      'america', 'england']
  end

  def start_x
    puts(@words)
  end
end
```

Or combine with an attribute reader:

```
class Game
  attr_reader :words

  def initialize
    @words = ['hat', 'cat', 'ate', 'run', 'eye', 'soup', 'date',
      'bake', 'wake', 'grape', 'apple', 'pride', 'drive',
      'tacos', 'linux', 'orange', 'purple', 'volume', 
      'liquid', 'palace', 'molasses', 'diamond', 'sausage',
      'america', 'england']
  end

  def start_x
    puts(words)
  end
end
```

All work the same way and will be used in different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because `words` is a *local variable* declared outside the methods.

You probably want to have an *instance variable* here. And it's usually a good idea to separate the game code from the data. So instead of hard-coding the words into the `Game` class, you *pass* the data upon initialization:

```
class Game
  def initialize(words)
    @words = words
  end

  def start_x
    puts @words
  end

  # ...
end
```

To call it:

```
words = %w[
  hat cat ate run eye soup date bake wake grape apple pride drive tacos linux
  orange purple volume liquid palace molasses diamond sausage america england
]

game = Game.new(words)
game.start_x
```

---

From here on, you could easily extract the data into a `words.txt` file:

```
hat
cat
ate
...
sausage
america
england
```

And load the data via:

```
words = File.readlines('words.txt' chomp: true)

game = Game.new(words)
game.start_x
```

This allows you to launch your game with different sets of words without having to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help you.

```
class Game
  attr_reader :words
  def initialize
    @words = %w[hat cat ate run eye soup date
                bake wake grape apple pride drive
                tacos linux orange purple volume
                liquid palace molasses diamond sausage
                america england]
  end
  # if users wins
  def win
    puts("congratulations! you win!")
  end
  # if user loses 
  def death
    puts("sorry! you die!")
  end
end
```

You can access the words like `Game.new.words`